# How to breakout BLE connection device count limit in Android? (Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The BLE connected device upper device limit is 7 , but I want to connect and send some data more than 7 device，How can i do ?

or other solution like when connected and send data complete , do disconnected command.

Thanks for watching.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. Just disconnect devices when you are done with them.

Comment: but i do this with multi thread? it's still wrong
Do  I need use multi thread? 
Colud you show me some example?
thanks